# Where condition for NULL values in order to display the null values

Tags: sql-server, window

I have the parameter which will will given null value.
 I want the where condition in which I will get the NULL values in all the columns when the parameter is null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That rather defeats the point of NULL values...

Answer (score 1):

From your dezcription I think this would work:

```
WHERE (@parameter1 IS NULL 
                AND COLUMN1 IS NULL)
         OR (@parameter1 IS NOT NULL
                AND COLUMN1 = @parameter1)
```